# Problema al insertar datos con ajax

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

Mi problema en si no es el insertar datos, dado a que estos se hacen de manera exitosa, el problema radica en que al insertar un dato, este se repite 2,3 o hasta 4 veces en la base de datos, otra cosa es que al entrar a la pagina y hacerlo por primera vez, este lo hace normal, pero mientras se hace este proceso como a la 3 vez de inserta datos, estos comienzan a repetirse. Dejo el código aquí abajo para ver si alguien puede ayudarme.

```js
function insertar(){               
          $.ajax({            
              type : 'POST',
              url  : '../indemnizaciones/tramite/Tinsertar.php',
              data: $('#form').serialize(),
              cache: false,
              success :  function(data) {                 
                  $("#Tresul").html(data).fadeIn();},
              complete: function(){
                   setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#Tresul').fadeOut();}, 10000);}})};
```

```html
<?php error_reporting(0); ?>
<div id="formulario">
<center>
    <div id="Tresul"></div>
</center><br>  
<form method="POST" id="tramite">
<input type="text" name="predio" style="display:none; " value="<?php echo $formulario['TPRE_IDPRE']; ?>">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1" style="margin-left: 250px;">

      <label>Oficio notificacion</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="oficioN" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;" <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_NONOT'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_NONOT']; ?>" <?php } ?> ><br><br>

      <label>Oficio solicitud autorizacion</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="oficioS" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;" <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_NSAUT'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_NSAUT']; ?>" <?php } ?>><br><br>

      <label>Oficio autorizacion</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="oficioA" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;"  <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_NOAUT'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_NOAUT']; ?>" <?php } ?>><br><br>
        <br>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
  
      <label>Fecha entrega notificacion</label><br>
      <input type="date" name="fechaN" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;"  <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_FENOT'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_FENOT']; ?>" <?php } ?>><br><br>

      <label>fecha solicitud autorizacion</label><br>
      <input type="date" name="fechaA" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;"  <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_FSAUT'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_FSAUT']; ?>" <?php } ?>><br><br>

      <label>fecha recepcion</label><br>
      <input type="date" name="fechaR" style="height: 30px; width: 80%;"  <?php if( $formularioT['TTRA_FAUTP'] <> "") { ?> value="<?php echo $formularioT['TTRA_FAUTP']; ?>" <?php } ?>><br><br>
  <br></div>
</div>
<center><br><center><br><button type="button" onclick="insertar();" id="boton">Guardar</button>

</form>
</div>
```

```html
<?php

require("../../conexion.php");

 $predio = $_POST['predio']; 
 $oficioN= $_POST['oficioN']; 
 $oficioS = $_POST['oficioS']; 
 $oficioA = $_POST['oficioA']; 
 $fechaN = $_POST['fechaN']; 
 $fechaA = $_POST['fechaA']; 
 $fechaR = $_POST['fechaR']; 


 $comprobar="SELECT * FROM ttramite WHERE TTRA_IDPRE='$predio';";
 $compro=$mysqli->query($comprobar);     


 if($compro->num_rows==0){

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO ttramite (TTRA_NONOT,TTRA_FENOT,TTRA_NSAUT,TTRA_FSAUT,TTRA_NOAUT,TTRA_FAUTP,TTRA_IDPRE) VALUES ('$oficioN','$fechaN','$oficioS','$fechaA','$oficioA','$fechaR','$predio');";

    if($resultado = $mysqli->query($consulta)){ 
     echo "<h5 style='color:#06A322;'>Registro guardado correctamente</h5>";
    } else {
     echo "<h5 style='color:#A30606;'>Imposible guardar, ocurrio un error</h5>";
    }
 }else{
        
  $consultaD="UPDATE ttramite SET TTRA_NONOT='$oficioN',TTRA_FENOT='$fechaN',TTRA_NSAUT='$oficioS', TTRA_FSAUT='$fechaA',TTRA_NOAUT='$oficioA',TTRA_FAUTP='$fechaR' WHERE TTRA_IDPRE='$predio';";


 if($resultadoD = $mysqli->query($consultaD)){
        echo "<h5 style='color:#0280BF;'>Registro modificado correctamente</h5>";
 } else {
         echo "<h5 style='color:#A30606;'>Imposible modificar, ocurrio un error</h5>";        
 }
 }
     
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que los datos se repiten cuando haces el submit, se enviaran los datas del formulario y luego hace el $.ajax la misma Acción, y por eso es que tiene el problema de los datos repetidos, La solución que yo propongo es no activar el submit del formulario, y solo usar el **$.ajax** para enivar los datos, solo tienes que cambiar el tipo de button de submit a button, ejm: `<button type="button">` y en el js remplasar el evento submit por evento click del button.

espero que sea de tu ayuda saludos!

Comment: lo hice amigo pero ahora no recoge los valores del form

Comment: bro, ya lo corregí bien, y si funciono perfectamente , dejare el código corregido arriba

Comment: me alegro que te sirviera saludos!